# AWS Block Devices name doesn't match with CentOS SoftLink

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, centos, cloud, block-device

On AWS EC2 Block Device is identified as `/dev/sda`, `/dev/sdf` and `/dev/sdg`, but inside EC2 CentOS instance when I do `ll /dev/sd*` it gives following:

```
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 4 Feb 17 03:10 /dev/sda -> xvde
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 4 Feb 17 03:10 /dev/sdj -> xvdj
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 4 Feb 17 03:10 /dev/sdk -> xvdk
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 5 Feb 17 03:10 /dev/sdk1 -> xvdk1
```

When I run ``` ec2-describe-instances --aws-access-key xxxxxx<MyKey>xxx --aws-secret-key xxxxxx<MyKey>xxx --region us-east-1 ``curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id`` | grep -i BLOCKDEVICE ``` output is as follow:

```
/dev/sda
/dev/sdf
/dev/sdg
```

I am wondering how to link these two: AWS GUI Console's Block Devices and within EC2 instance Block Devices?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a device mapping alias problem. You can see more details with a solution here:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=255240

Make sure you take backups of everything before making any changes!